# Why can't I declare and define a member variable in different lines in a class?

Tags: c++, class, oop

As you can see, in the "Demo" class I declared "id". But I can't initialize it in the next line (I know, I could have done this in the same line, but still). I can do this same exact thing in case of "a" in the main function. Why???

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Demo {
    public:
    int id;
    id = 90;
    int setID(int x)
    {
        id = x;
    }
};

int main() {
    int a;
    a = 90;
    Demo d;
    d.setID(50);
    cout<<a<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In `main` you are *not* *initializing* `a`. You are *assigning* to it post-initialization. Initialization and assignment are two very different things.

Comment: I recommend getting into the habit of using *constructors* to initialize your classes.  This will help when initialization becomes more complex in later projects.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: A default member initializer *does* operate via the constructors.  And plain assignments in the constructor shouldn’t be encouraged (since they aren’t initializers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this is how the language works. `main` is a function. Inside a function commands get executed one by one:

1) Create variable `a` of type `int`. 
2) Assign value of 90 to `a` 
3) Create object `d` of type `Demo` 
and so on.

But `class Demo {
    public:
    int id;
    int setID(int x)
    {
        id = x;
    }
};`

is not a function. It is a declaration of a class. It is nothing more than description of an entity. You cannot execute commands inside a description. You can say "this class has `int a`" and that's it

Comment: However, in C++11 and later, you can now initialize class members directly in their declarations: `public: int id = 90;` But if you want to declare and initialize them separately (which you must do pre-C++11), you have to use the constructor for that

Comment: @JoydwipMohajon You're welcome. buddy! Please accept mine or Brian's answer if either has helped you

Answer (score 3):

A function body is a sequence of statements. A class body is a sequence of member declarations. Most kinds of statements can't go inside a class body, because they're not valid member declarations. You can only put "runnable code" inside a class if it's nested inside a function.

If there's a piece of code you want to have run every time a class is instantiated, put it in the constructor. If there's a piece of code you want to have run only once, when the class is defined, there's no mechanism for doing that in C++.